# Is it possible to create a CoreOS cluster environment on Ubuntu machines?

Tags: ubuntu, coreos, etcd, flannel, fleet

I have been using CoreOS for a little while and like the environment I get when running etcd, fleet and flannel.  I would like to use these services in a production environment to create a docker cluster. However using CoreOS machines is not an option for me, as will be working on servers running Ubuntu (and replacing the OS is not an option).  Is it possible to run etcd, fleet and flannel on ubuntu machines to create ubuntu machines that will behave like CoreOS machines?

If not I was considering just running CoreOS vagrant boxes inside of my servers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of those services should run just fine on any Linux machine.

Comment: Thats great! Is it possible to run etcd and fleet as containers on ubuntu systems (as in there are already public containers that will run them) or must they be installed the regular way?

Comment: There is an existing etcd container, I don't think there is a fleet one, but it shouldn't be too hard to create one out of the static binary.